# Is it possible to compress the rtmp vedio streaming on the transit nodes of a networking?

Tags: tcp, video-streaming, rtmp, sdn, openflow

I want to do some labtory work using a network like this:
[image]

I want to transmit rtmp video streaming packets from the "server" node to the "client" node. The rtmp packets will be transmitted through node1 or node2 or node3 between the server node and the client node.

Is it possible that I compress the rtmp video streaming on node1/node2/node3? If it is possible, how? Do I have to capture the rtmp packets one node1/node2/node3 and then compress them and then resend the packets out from node1/node2/node3 to the client? Can I just do the compress work on lower layers (network layer/ data-link layer) of the network?

I am really curious about this. I will be really grateful if anybody can help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg which keeps two tcp connection instead of using one rtmp connection.

Answer (score 1):

The approach for a server network, generally tries to solve:

- Capacity: Extends the capacity of system, for example, to serve 100k clients.
- Quality: Deliver stream to client as near as possible, for normally distributed clients, whatever the number of clients. For example, you got 10 clients to serve, but they are in total different provinces or even countries.

For `Quality`, a reverse proxy like nginx works very well, like this;

```
client ---<--RTMP---   Nginx ----<--RTMP--- Server
```

Note that the Proxy never increase the system capacity, the maximum clients is limited by the Server. So if you wants to increase the capacity, generally it also play like but more than a `proxy`, please use media cluster, like [Edge of SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/wiki/v4_EN_SampleRTMPCluster):

```
1k client -<--RTMP--- SRS(Edge) --<--RTMP---+- SRS Origin Server
...                                         |
1k client  -<--RTMP--- SRS(Edge) --<--RTMP--+
...                                         |
1k client  -<--RTMP--- SRS(Edge) --<--RTMP--+
```

Each Origin Server could serve about 1k SRS Edge server, and each Edge Server serves about 1k~3k clients.